# How can I calculate the following probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

Does it using poisson distribution to calculate the probability? Thank you!

Comment: You just have to use the definition of $F_Z$ and for some questions the symetrie of $N(0,1)$.

Comment: $Z$ has a standard normal distribution

Answer (score 1):

Z is following Normal Distribution. The values you are given are the cumulative function's values. So $P(Z \le z)=F_Z (z)$. According to this $F_Z(0.3)=P(Z \le 0.3)$ and $F_Z(1.2)=P(Z\le 1.2)$.

1. $P(Z \le 1.2)= 0.885$
2. $P(Z \ge 0.3) = 1-P(Z \le 0.3) = 1-0.618=0.382$
3. $P(Z \le -1.2)= 1-P(Z \le 1.2)= 1- F_Z (1.2) = 1-0.885=0.115$
4. $P(0.3 \le Z \lt 1.2) = P(Z \lt 1.2) - P(Z \le 0.3) = 0.885-0.618=0.267$
5. $P(-1.2 \lt Z \le 0.3) = P(Z \le 0.3) - P(Z \lt -1.2) = P(Z \le 0.3) - [1-P(Z \lt 1.2)] = P(Z \lt 1.2) - 1 + P(Z \le 0.3) = 0.885 + 0.618 - 1 = 0.503$
6. $P(|Z| \lt 1.2) = P(-1.2 \lt Z \le 1.2) = P(Z \lt -1.2) - P(Z \lt 1.2) = $ ... see above